# Connecting GWT and Restlet together

Tags: java, gwt, restlet

I have a Restlet API and a GWT client and I have been following the Restlet tutorial (http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/21-restlet/318-restlet/303-restlet.html) here on connecting the two together. My issue is that their tutorial only exposes the API on that local machine e.g.

```
Directory dir = new Directory(getContext(), LocalReference.createFileReference(new File("war/")));
router.attachDefault(dir);
```

But i want to expose it on a hostname and port instead. I am a beginner at GWT so its rather confusing. Can someone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to be able to make a call i.e. from a browser? restlet has a standalone server component which you can use for this purpose.

Read on [here](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.0/firstSteps#part04).